# Using CMDeviceMotion and CMAttitude to isolate vertical or horizontal acceleration

Tags: ios

I'm trying to isolate either a vertical or horizontal acceleration component assuming device orientation may be continuously changing.

Prior to having gyroscope data and CMAttitude, this was impossible because we only had the acceleration data. Now that we have both acceleration is userAcceleration and orientation via CMAttitude, it seems it should be possible to adjust the acceleration data by the attitude data in order to isolate a particular absolute direction of acceleration. This is a bit different from using a reference frame because I'm expecting the device orientation to be constantly changing. Think armband, etc... In my case,

I'd like to be able to capture either strictly vertical, or strictly horizontal acceleration values regardless of how the device orientation may be changing. The geometry for this is a little beyond me and I'd appreciate some advice.

Comment: It would be useful if you could tell us a little more about the kind of real-world measurement you're trying to perform.  Is it simply to count the number of arm swings?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not familiar with the iOS APIs but I can give the math answer.

1. Determine the orientation with gyroscope+accelerometer sensor fusion. I hope iOS has an API for that as it's relatively complicated (if not let us know and I will elaborate). This seems to be what you call CMAttitude. The orientation should be expressed as a quaternion or a matrix, it represents the rotation between a fixed reference frame (most probably North-East-Down, but it depends on the API) and the local reference frame attached to your device.
2. Take the vector read from the accelerometer (in the local reference frame), and rotate it with the opposite rotation of your orientation. The opposite of a rotation is the quaternion conjugate or the matrix transpose. Rotating a vector is done via quaternion multiplication or matrix multiplication. This gives you the acceleration vector in the fixed reference frame.
3. The Z-component of the acceleration in the fixed reference frame is the vertical acceleration. The norm of the XY-components (sqrt(x^2+y^2)) is the horizontal acceleration. Don't forget to subtract the gravity from vertical acceleration. This assumes a North-East-Down reference frame again, but most other fixed reference frames would only require you to swap X,Y,Z appropriately.

The implementation shall be trivial if iOS has the right APIs. If you have the choice prefer quaternions over matrices as the implementation would run faster. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: I just implemented your answer (See below). For some reasons the horizontal acceleration I am getting varies heavily depending if I point the device to the South, East, West or North. Is this by purpose or does this indicate an implementation error on my side?

Answer (score 1):

I just implemented **marcv81** answer.

```
-(void)isolateHorizontalMotionFromMotionData:(CMDeviceMotino *)newMotion
{
    //Quaternion Conjugation
    CMQuaternion quaternion = newMotion.attitude.quaternion;
    GLKQuaternion original_quaternion = GLKQuaternionMake(quaternion.x, quaternion.y, quaternion.z, quaternion.w);
    GLKQuaternion conjugated_quaternion = GLKQuaternionConjugate(original_quaternion);

    //Rotation of Accelerometer vector with quanternion
    GLKVector3 acceleromationVector = GLKVector3Make(newMotion.userAcceleration.x, newMotion.userAcceleration.y, newMotion.userAcceleration.z);

    GLKVector3 accelerometionVector_toReferenceFrame = GLKQuaternionRotateVector3(conjugated_quaternion, acceleromationVector);

    //Horizontal Acceleration
    float horizontalAcceleration = sqrtf(powf(accelerometionVector_toReferenceFrame.x,2)+powf(accelerometionVector_toReferenceFrame.y,2));
}
```

Comment: The behaviour you experience is not by design. I can think of a source of error: is your z vector pointing up/down? I don't know the iPhone specs but it could be z or y pointing up/down. You would have to change the last line. I suggest displaying vectors/angles at different points to help debugging.

Comment: Just to make sure if I understood it correctly. Let's assume one holds the iPhone fixed in his hands. Now he is doing a straight squat. While doing this the **horizontalAcceleration** should be nearly, 0 not matter in what orientation he is holding the device? I need this to measure a car's horizontal accelerations, like breaking driving in a curve or accelerating. This should be achievable by using the mechanism you provided, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly! What you can do instead of the last line of code is print all the 3 coordinates of the accelerometer vector converted in the reference frame, and see if you get the same values for the same acceleration regardless of the device orientation.