# How to measure acceleration and deceleration of a vehicle?

Tags: ios, iphone, accelerometer

Given the following data

- Orientation of the device (CMAttitude - Quaternion or Rotation Matrix)
- Acceleration Vector (CMAcceleration - userAcceleration --> without gravity)

Is there a way to get the acceleration and deceleration of a car placing the device in an arbitrary orientation into the car?

If not what would be the best approach to get the acceleration and deceleration by positioning the device in a fixed position inside the car?

Any hints or solution approached would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
I tried to implement the suggested approach from this answer [Using CMDeviceMotion and CMAttitude to isolate vertical or horizontal acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097692/using-cmdevicemotion-and-cmattitude-to-isolate-vertical-or-horizontal-accelerati) to isolate the vertical and horizontal acceleration.

I set the reference frame to **CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXMagneticNorthZVertical**

```
//Quaternion Conjugation
CMQuaternion quaternion = newMotion.attitude.quaternion;
GLKQuaternion conjugated_quaternion = GLKQuaternionMake(quaternion.x, quaternion.y, quaternion.z, quaternion.w);
conjugated_quaternion = GLKQuaternionConjugate(conjugated_quaternion);

//Rotation of Accelerometer vector with quanternion
GLKVector3 acceleromationVector = GLKVector3Make(newMotion.userAcceleration.x, newMotion.userAcceleration.y, newMotion.userAcceleration.z);
GLKVector3 accelerometionVector_toReferenceFrame = GLKQuaternionRotateVector3(conjugated_quaternion, acceleromationVector);

//Horizontal Acceleration
float horizontalAcceleration = sqrtf(powf(accelerometionVector_toReferenceFrame.x,2)+powf(accelerometionVector_toReferenceFrame.y,2));
```

In the suggested answer the reference frame which should be used is **North-East-Down**. Would this be the same than **CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXMagneticNorthZVertical**? Or could it be that this is the wron reference frame and thus the results of this implementation turn out to be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for an algorithm not a functionality in the device itself. I don't believe there is a feature in any apple's iDevice that allows you to get the current ** deceleration/acceleration**

Use **The Kinematic Equations**: `a = (Vf - Vi) / t`

- **a**: Acceleration
- **Vf**: final velocity
- **Vi**: initial velocity
- **t**: time difference between **Vi** and **Vf**

This is what I would do to get the **de/acceleration**:

1. Calculate `Vf = d/t` say the car moves for a 10 km (this is d `distance` in meters) in 10 seconds (this is t `time` in seconds) you should be able get the final velocity `Vf`.
2. Assume `Vi = 0` at first calculation then keep track of it by assigning `current-Vi = previous-Vf`
3. Calculate de/acceleration `a = (Vf - Vi) / t`

Remember **deceleration is just a *negative* acceleration**

**Edit**: You can also use `userAcceleration` defined in [CMDeviceMotion.h](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/coremotion/reference/CMDeviceMotion_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CMDeviceMotion/userAcceleration)

Comment: *Every* iOS device provides the most recent acceleration data via the CMMotionManager class.

Comment: @Caleb - Thanks. I've just added a ref to it!

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Getting the acceleration data is not the issue I am facing. I basically want to be able to get the forward moving acceleration and the deceleration of a car, no matter how the device is orientated inside the car. I just edited my question to make it more clearly.